# how to require a specific file using duojs

Tags: frontend, package-managers, duo.js

I need to include a library that is present on github, but is not well-packaged; using [Duo.js](http://duojs.org/)

At the moment of writing I am using the following to achieve what I desire:

> [bower](http://bower.io)
>   [gulp](http://gulpjs.com)
>   [main-bower-files](https://github.com/ck86/main-bower-files)

Bower just downloades the library.
Gulp, with main-bower-files are useful to override the single package options and setup a so-called "main file" that I can build.

Example:

```
gulp.task('copy-libs', function () {
  return gulp.src(bowerFiles({ env: 'development' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/libs/'));
});
```

bower.json file:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "cash": "sudo-js/cash",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.2",
    "delorean": "~0.8.7",
    "react": "~0.12.2"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "cash": {
      "main": {
        "development": "build/debug/cash.js"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can i achieve this with duojs?
The documentation is quite thin regarding libraries that does **not** ship with a valid `component.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the path to an entry file for your lib. It won't be as clean as just specifying `user/repo`, but it'll get the job done.

For example, when including [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) from [twbs/bootstrap](http://github.com/twbs/bootstrap)

```
require('twbs/bootstrap@v3.3.2:dist/js/bootstrap.js');
// repo:        twbs/bootstrap
// version/tag: v3.3.2
// path:        dist/js/bootstrap.js
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work out-of-the-box since it assumes you have the `jQuery` global... so you need to add this *above* the previous line.

```
jQuery = require('components/jquery'); // leave out `var` so it becomes a global
```

This includes jQuery from the wonderful [components](http://github.com/components) project. (they package up popular libs so they can be consumed by various package managers.

Also, it turns out there is a `components/bootstrap` that *is* properly packaged with a `component.json`.

So, you can actually make bootstrap work with the following:

```
jQuery = require('components/jquery');
require('components/bootstrap');
```

For the other libraries that aren't as common, you can use the process mentioned first to specify the path to the right JS/CSS file. (ie: `user/repo@version:path`)